# Intel System Studio IoT edition installation error: SetUp Wizard ended prematurely; Integrity checking failed

Tags: intel, iot, intel-iot

I'm trying to install Intel System Studio IoT edition and it keeps failing. Can anyone help fix the error?

[image: SetUp Wizard Ended Prematurely; Integrity Check Failed]

Comment: Maybe the file you downloaded wasn't complete, or your computer has bad RAM?  Try checksumming the file, if Intel publishes checksums for the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the Intel System Studio 2018 Beta, which carries forward the IoT functionality (docker containers) https://software.intel.com/sites/intel-system-studio-2018-beta/#/